# In C, I have a floating point variable decreasing by an incorrect amount

Tags: c, variables, cs50

I'm writing a program in C to calculate change owed. You're supposed to enter in a value and get a message back displaying something like: "Your change is: x quarters, x dimes..."

The system works through 4 "for" loops. Each checks if a variable, x, is less than the value of the user inputted value (money). If so, then x is increased by some coin value (i.e. 0.25), a variable that counts a specific coin is increased, and the value inputted by the user is decreased by some coin value.

The problem is that the value inputted by the user (stored in a float called money) is decreased by an incorrect amount. 1 - 0.25 should be 0.75, right? Yet, for some reason, my program changes the value of 'money' to 0.500000.

Here's the code:

```
float money = 0.00;
int q = 0;
int d = 0;
int n = 0;
int p = 0;
float x = 0.00;

printf("Enter amount: ");
money = GetFloat(); // This function is part of a library called cs50.h

for (x = 0.00; x < money; (x = x + 0.25)) {
    q++;
    money = (money - 0.25); // This, and everything else like this, is the problem
}

for (x = 0; x < money; (x = x + 0.10)) {
    d++;
    money = (money - 0.10);
}

for (x = 0; x < money; (x = x + 0.05)) {
    n++;
    money = (money - 0.05);
}

for (x = 0; x < money; (x = x + 0.01)) {
    p++;
    money = (money - 0.01);
}

printf("Your change is: %i quarters, %i dimes, %i nickles, and %i pennies.\n", q, d, n, p);
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger yet? If your answer is not "yes", then please delete this question, go do so, and come back when you have a real question.

Comment: @JimLewis While I completely agree with you, the fact that the OP is getting a value like `0.500000` when he expects `0.75` indicates a logic error, and not a floating point precision issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

didnt really read your story but 0.500 is exactly what your for loop produce

```
for (x = 0.00; x < money; (x = x + 0.25)) {
    q++;
    money = (money - 0.25); // This, and everything else like this, is the     problem
}
```

assume money is 1:
after 1st iteration: x becomes to 0.25 and money becomes 0.75
then you have 2nd iteration: x becomes to 0.5 and money becomes 0.5
after 2nd iteration, your loop is over. therefore money = 0.5f

and all your loop has exactly the same problem. Remember that your loop only stops when the condition x < money does not hold.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't understand this sooner. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your loops are correct? I think you may not be getting what your expecting because the logic of the loops is not right. For example, I think the first loop will have the following outcome if money = 1.00 to start.

```
x     q     money   x<money
0.00  1     0.75    1   
0.25  2     0.50    1
0.50  3     0.25    0 (exit loop)
```

Comment: q will not reach 3 and money will not reach 0.25